# What do we use glyph for?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, glyph

What is a glyph and what do we use it for especially in context of silverlight and xaml?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Glyphs are a low-level depiction of a character to be drawn on-screen. A good article on them is available on MSDN: [Introduction to the GlyphRun Object and Glyphs Element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms748985(v=VS.100).aspx).

Posting a link for you read, I think it is better than simply rehashing the information in my answer (it has pictures and links for further reading).

Comment: "This topic is no longer available" -- this is why we like to see rehashing of the information instead of links :)

Comment: Thanks @DavidBožjak. I've updated the link. It appears MSDN changed their routes so the link now requires the version information as part of the url e.g. `(v=VS.100)`. When you see the content, you'll understand why it wasn't copied into the answer.

Answer (score 0):

See the following MSDN article for info on Glyphs:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb979862(VS.95).aspx

you can also see more examples here:

http://www.wynapse.com/Silverlight/Silverlight_Glyph_Explorer.aspx